# Specialization of a template to a nested class type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, traits

Is there anyway to specialize a trait template for a nested class?  I've tried it in the three places noted below, each with the given error.  I've seen questions regarding specializing nested template classes, but that's not what I'm trying to do here-- I'm trying to specialize a trait class that is used by the nested class.

The TraitUser class makes use of the definitions within the Trait as specialized to a specific type T.  Perhaps most relevantly, it uses a trait member to initialize a base class.

```
template<T>
class TraitUser:public X<typename Trait<T>::Type>
{
  //Trait<T> gets used in here
};

//class A;
//class A::B;   <-incomplete type used in nested name

//template<>
//struct Trait<A::B>
//{};

class A
{
private:
    //class B;

    //template<>         <-explicit specialization at class scope
    //struct Trait<B>
    //{};

    class B:TraitUser<B>
        {};
};


//template<>        <- specialization after instantiation
//struct Trait<A::B>
//{};
```

It looks like the root of the trouble is not being able to forward declare a nested class and also not being able to define a specialization inside a class declaration.

I'm trying this under clang using C++11.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand your question. Where is `Trait` to be used, what's its relationship to `TraitUser`, is `TraitUser` a template or non-template, is `A` a non-template?

Comment: @MarkB, Sorry, I'm trying to boil down some rather complexly inter-related code into something simple and seem to have overdone it...  Trait contains a few relative type aliases and function pointers that are used by TraitUser.  TraitUser is a template class.  A and B are not templates themselves, but inherit from templates.  TraitUser calls on the Trait specialization to know what functions to call and types to use, it also uses one of the Trait types to parameterize one of its own template base classes as I now show in the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some complicated declaration ordering here:

```
template <class T>
struct Trait;

template <class T>
struct X
{};

template<class T>
class TraitUser:public X<typename Trait<T>::Type>
{
  //Trait<T> gets used in here
};

class A
{
private:
    class B;
};


template<>
struct Trait<A::B>
{
    typedef int Type;
};

class A::B : public TraitUser<B>
{};
```

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I over simplified in the question.  I've tried to update it...  There's the additional tangle that TraitUser<B> uses Trait<B>::Type as a parameter to a template base class...  I think that's what triggered the "specialize after instantiation" error-- it's being instantiated in the declaration of B.

Comment: @GB Okay. That's a bit more challenging.

Comment: @GB If you tell me that `B` needs to be complete in the definition of `A`, I will cry.

Comment: @Casey-- that did it!  I made a small edit to make TraitUser<B> a friend of A.  This isn't clear from the skeleton code, but the Trait template has static members that need to be defined externally, and the compiler gets miffed about referencing the private nested class.